# ansible-doc ios_command not found

Tags: ansible, cisco-ios

The Ansible docs state that the `ios_command` module is a core module. However, if I look for docs on this I get:

```
$ ansible-doc ios_command
module ios_command not found in /usr/share/ansible:...
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Ansible version.
`ios_command` is available since version 2.1.
Also there may be situation when you have several different versions of Ansible on your machine (like apt and pip).

On my machine:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.1.2.0
$ ansible-doc -l | grep ios_command
ios_command                        Run arbitrary commands on ios devices.
```